# Fluent Validation for enum type required field

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a simple enum for validation form.

Painting type is  a required field , so I want to make rule for them in Fluent Validator.What should i specify *.NotNull()* or *.NotEmpty()*?

```
public enum VehiclePaintingType
{
    Pearly = 1,
    Metallic,
    Opaque     
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the validation you are applying. `.NotNull` would not be useful as an enum cannot be null

`.NotEmpty` checks the value is not null, an empty string, whitespace or the default value (for value types). So unless you are going to have a default value of `none` then the validation will most probably not achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Scrobi (and according to the [docs](https://fluentvalidation.net/built-in-validators)), `.NotNull()` ensures that the specified property is not null, while `.NotEmpty()` ensures that it is not null, an empty string or a whitespace.
So, for your case, it is best to use `.NotEmpty()`.

Comment: `NotEmpty` ensures the property is not null [docs](https://fluentvalidation.net/built-in-validators)
enums are also value types so they cannot be null.

Comment: I'm editing this to include your clarification. Thanks, @Scrobi.